# scalikejdbc: Query/Result caching

Tags: database, postgresql, scala, caching, scalikejdbc

I am using the scalikejdbc library to access my Postgres database. The driver I am using is the default `org.postgresql.Driver`. I am trying to introduce query/result caching but I cannot find any evidence whether scalalike does this by default or if it even supports this. I skimmed through the `TypesafeConfigReader` class but could not find any configuration property indicative of such a functionality. My last resort would be to implement a simple application level cache but I want to know if this is supported somehow by default. In their official docs I could not find something definitive either.

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered in the [scalikejdbc issue tracker](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/issues/1525#issuecomment-1058043598). So I'm quoting

> There is no built-in query cache/result support at this moment. I would suggest using a different cache library such as https://github.com/cb372/scalacache to reduce method calls.